# compiling for iOS 14.0, but module 'MockTechPost' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 15.0

Tags: ios, swift

i have seen other post simmilar to this and their solution is either upgrade it to ios 15 or put @available ios xx, I've done both and still got this error, are there any other solution? thank you

```
<unknown>:0: error: compiling for iOS 14.0, but module 'MockTechPost' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 15.0: /Users/fdika24/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MockTechPost-gkosutlxcjcxfobkjgdzjwenfqcr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MockTechPost.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MockTechPost.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PostsDataSource~partial.swiftmodule
Command MergeSwiftModule failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by deleting the folder corresponding to the application for which compilation failed in:
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
Then recompile. The folder is re-created and compilation went well, at least for me.

Comment: Yup deleting derived data works for me as well.

Answer (score 11):

So you have to set both **Project** and **Target** version.

**Project:**

[image: Project]

**Target:**

[image: Target]

Answer (score 8):

I just had this and after checking all the settings were correct in the Build Settings tabs a "Product -> Clean Build Folder" solved it without manually having to delete folders.

Comment: This worked for me, and seems the faster/cleaner solution. Thanks for letting me know that option exists ✨

Comment: this also worked for me. Weirdly enough the keyboard shortcut didnt work, I had to go into product-clean build , and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it,and this might sound crazy but the solution is not upgrading it into ios 15, adding a reference to the Main storyboard is the solution, crazy huh

Comment: Can confirm, same situation for me

Answer (score 1):

Product -> Clean build folder -> Build. Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this when trying to run a unit test.  Problem was my test target deployment info hadn't been updated after I updated the deployment info for the app.

Comment: This worked for me. Then cleaned build folder and built again.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting derived data worked for me ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
but also make sure that other targets have the same deployment target like your app ones have such as Tests, UITests tests etc. After that recompile the app and everything should work

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Extension have also a look to Build Settings
[image: Build Settings]

Answer (score -1):

Click on your project and go to "General" tab and make sure the deployment target for your project is iOS 15.0 as shown here:

[image]

Also, check the same for this configuration property has in "Build Settings" tab

[image: deployment target]

Comment: already did that, that's the problem

Comment: @Farhandika I have added more details, hope this solves your issue. If not, are you comfortable in sharing the project files in some way?

Comment: thank you for your help, already did that also, and it's fixed with a very unconventional ways